# Emacs hide/show (hs-minor-mode) for imports/includes

Tags: eclipse, emacs

hs-minor-mode in Emacs makes it possible to hide the cumbersome initial comment block so that one can get quickly to the code.

[image: hs-minor-mode]

Is there a way to duplicate in Emacs what Eclipse (and other) IDEs do to the initial import blocks? A solution that works for C++ includes as well as for Java imports would be nice.

[image: Eclipse-elide]

Comment: Question is only about programming is the most remote sense.  Likely off-topic here, on-topic at superuser.

Comment: Questions about programmer *tools* are on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the various folding modes and HideShow mode in Emacs. The original Emacs folding-mode has the downside that it requires you to add some additional markers to the code, which I find cumbersome and they don't really help with readability IMHO.

CEDET has a semantic folding mode that will probably be able to do what you want (I haven't looked at it for a while but CEDET/semantic is pretty good at this sort of functionality).

Comment: Right.. I know about hs-hide-initial-comment-block, but I don't see hs-hide-(initial)-include-block(s). I see that hideshow is built on regexps, so I guess the question is how to come up with a regexp that will capture only the blocks, and the necessary hooks.

Comment: The hint to http://cedet.sourceforge.net/ is nice. It looks quite useful, even if after an initial look it's not clear whether it solves this question.